# condition vs division

Tags: c, performance, division

given the following statement which is executed a lot:

```
iNormVal = iVal / uRatio;
```

would the following make more sense (performance wise) if `uRatio == 1` most (90%) of the time?

```
if(uRatio > 1)
iNormVal = iVal / uRatio;
else
iNormVal = iVal;
```

thanks..

Comment: Are the values integers or doubles or floats?

Comment: @Ed prefix i is int, u is unsigned int

Comment: given his use of "hungarian" notation I assume integers, with uRatio unsigned.

Comment: Also, your example returns iVal if uRatio is 0. If that's by design. fine. Otherwise, is this the right way to prevent a division by zero?

Comment: @MrLister good point, but case is handled in ommited code..

Comment: I can hardly recommend to do so unless you find that it does boost speed (proof), and you need that speed. Honestly, this code is just going to raise eyebrows come time to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) this to get a measurement, it's too hard to guess. The compiler might decide you're wrong and remove the test, so check with and without optimizing.

The actual cost of an (integer) division might be rather low, especially on modern desktop-class processors. According to [this PDF](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), the costs on modern (Wolfdale/Nehalem/Sandy Bridge) of a 32/32-bit division are 14-23/17-28/20-28 cycles respectively. So, if you really do this a lot, it might add up. In that case, look into parallel (vectorized) options if possible.

I would try to avoid it if at all possible, since it introduces a branch. Branches have two disadvantages: they make the code more complex by introducing multiple paths that the programmer reading the code has to understand, and they can also introduce execution overhead.

Comment: +1, less branching means more straightforward and easily understandable code.

Comment: couldn't agree more in general, was considering this as i think it doesn't really confuse the code and is going to be executed heavily. profiling will tell, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Since you spotted this as a potential bottleneck, it's *very* likely this spot is totally *irrelevant* for your app's overall speed. Seriously, humans, even guru programmers, are notoriously bad at spotting real bottlenecks. (The difference is that good programmers admit and preach that, while juniors keep spending time for optimizing irrelevant spots.)

Generally I found this approach to optimizations most helpful:

1. If speed is a major concern, schedule considerable time for optimizations to be done before releasing your app.
2. *Design* your code so that it doesn't sport inherent pessimizations.
3. *Implement* it the way it's easiest to understand the code. Prevent *obvious pessimizations* (like passing parameters by value instead of reference), but don't get overexcited.
4. *Check* if it is too slow. If so *profile* the app and identify the hot spots.
5. Put resources into *optimizing* (and thereby potentially *obfuscating*) those hot spots only, iteratively profiling to check which changes help.
6. Stop when the app is fast enough.

(It's different for library code, obviously, but these few steps would carry you a long way.)

Comment: i agree, but the big picture you are describing doesn't seem to me reason enough to avoid tweeking something in your code that will improve perf (if perf is what you want & if you are sure that it will indeed improve). i'm not talking about a major change here and i'm not establishing bottlenecks.. that said thanks for your post and i must say i agree..

Comment: @nantonop: The point is that you are *not* sure this will improve performance, and in all likelihood it will not.

Comment: @nantonop: The reason to avoid pointless optimizing is that ___1)___ it drains resources needed to optimize the spots that count, and ___2)___ it might [introduce subtle bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848167/condition-vs-division#comment-11051422).

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Yes, you see this was WHY i posted the question in the first place..

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Is the code in a performance critical application? If so then it may help perf wise. If not well then I would usually err on the side or readibility and not introduce the extra if statement.

Even if it is in a performance critical application, it is usually the external boundary interactions that account for 95% of the perf time such as interactions with databases or external services. Compilers usually execute very quickly and if statements are very cheap. When we usually profile our code, it is rare that we would make a change such as what you have described for perf reasons only. Misuse of looping and the like may sometimes prop up but we rarely add if statements like described.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to go with branching then you could check first for the common case. It is slightly more readable and should be slightly better performance wise.

```
if(uRatio <= 1) {
    iNormVal = iVal;
}
else {
    iNormVal = iVal / uRatio;
}
```

To be more readable you could add a local variable with a good name that holds the result of the expression.

```
unsigned int uSmallRatio = uRatio <= 1;
if(uSmallRatio) {
    iNormVal = iVal;
}
else {
    iNormVal = iVal / uRatio;
}
```

The compiler could optimize this into the same machine code as the first approach. I'm not sure about this though.

Similarly you could do this but it is not pretty:

```
iNormVal = uRatio <= 1 ? iVal : iVal / uRatio;
```

Finally another approach would be:

```
iNormVal = iVal;
if(uRatio > 1) { /*explain why you do this so it won't be changed by somebody else*/
    iNormVal = iVal / uRatio;
}
```

I'm sure there are other approaches to consider.

Regards...

Answer (score 1):

The if clause will actually most likely make the program slower. Branching is *really bad* for performance because modern processors are [pipelined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline), and branches prevent the pipeline from being fully effective. This is such a significant issue that considerable effort goes into [branch prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction), but that's not going to help in this case. Even if the prediction is right 90% of the time, that means an empty pipeline 10% of the time, which is a lot worse than an int division (expecially when taking into account that the if clause itself takes time).

But most likely it does not matter at all because your code spends most of its time in a completely different place, making this whole question a huge waste of time.

Comment: You are certainly right in theory. But this branching is likely just a few bytes of machine code, so in practice it might not matter at all. _If_ you want to know this, you really need to measure and compare (and be aware that this might very well differ from platform to platform). But that's really only worth the trouble if you _know_ this spot even matters.

Answer (score 1):

Most performance issues are either ideological (you designed way wrong), or implementation of a proven slower algorithm (given choices).

Beyond that, performance gains are going to be at the assembly level, and will be platform dependent.

I can hardly recommend this as an actual concern for performance, unless you're really strapped for performance, at which point you need to go check the above first.

All you've done is raise the eyebrows of the person that will maintain your code. Hope you have a lazy programmer that leaves stuff alone, or you'll end up losing this code anyway.

Because you have no guarantees at this level, of how code will perform on different platforms given different compiler, compiler options, and optimizations, you may even lose the code to compiler optimization. It's best to focus on larger issues.